# Nested strings in bash command

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am attempting to write a script to list all the shebang lines in python files.

What I would like to do is

```
sudo bash -c 'for logf in $(find / -name "*.py"); do fgrep '#!/usr/bin' "$logf"; done'
```

This gives error `bash: !/usr/bin': event not found`. I understand why, although the meaning of the error is unclear.

The trouble is I can't figure out how to pass a string to `bash` which includes another string without command execution.

If I leave off the "#!" it works, but of course includes a number of other lines.

I have tried practically every combination of escape and string without success.

Comment: you could do this simply with the `find` command: `find / -name "*.py" -exec fgrep '#!/usr/bin' {} \; -print`

Comment: Escaping the # didn't help?

Comment: Do you want to make this command work (with minimal changes), or nest strings in general?

Comment: @MichaelHomer At this stage I just want to make it work. I have had similar problems before, so would like to understand if there is a solution. I retried the plain command suggested by @Ketan with `sudo`, and this works. As I am only using a single command there is no need for the bash command.

Comment: fgrep '\\#\\!/usr/bin' worked for me.

Comment: @jai_s Thanks '\\#\\!/usr/bin' works. I obviously didn't have enough escapes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I have 2 versions which work.
Note I have made a couple of changes (to only find shebang at beginning of line) and to allow white space after shebang.

```
sudo bash -c 'for logf in $(find / -name "*.py"); do grep '^\\#\\!/usr/bin' "$logf"; done'
```

For some reason when I tried to allow white space after shebang I couldn't get it to work.

Even better (and simpler)

```
sudo find / -name "*.py" -exec grep '^#! */usr/bin' {} \;
```